# PayPal getting DPRP_DISABLED - How to enable DPRP

Tags: paypal

As I try to create an `Agreement` I'm currently getting:

```
response-code: 400  details: name: DPRP_DISABLED    message: DPRP is disabled for this merchant.    details: null   debug-id: *********** information-link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DPRP_DISABLED
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException.createFromHttpErrorException(PayPalRESTException.java:72)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:431)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:295)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:228)
    at com.paypal.api.payments.Agreement.create(Agreement.java:145)
```

I know I need to upgrade my sandbox account to pro but in contrary as stated in the [sandbox account documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/):

> On the Profile page of the Business account, click the Account type: Upgrade to Pro link.

there is no such thing to click:

[image]

So how can I activate DPRP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please kindly reach the [PayPal MTS team](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/)  to help you enable the DPRP access for your sandbox account.

Comment: I called support and they said it's not possible to process credit card payments *without*  a PayPal account - I was recommended to take a look at braintree.

Comment: Yes, direct credit card payments only opens to the limited countries so far.For Sandbox account, you can be granted the permission for testing purpose.